# Java packages: no class def found

Tags: java, package, noclassdeffounderror, instrumentation

so I've tried many of the solutions that are present in this website but none could help me.

The problem:
I have my project files structured like this:

cnv/webserver/aplication/insProj.java

cnv/webserver/aplication/IntFactorization.java

and both are in the package webserver.aplication.

to compile and run i do this:
starting at the folder cnv and with the $CLASSPATH=/home/ll/Documents/cnv

```
cd webserver/aplication
javac -source 1.4 insProj.java
javac IntFactorization.java
cd ..
cd ..
java -XX:-UseSplitVerifier webserver.aplication.insProj ./webserver/aplication/IntFactorization.class
java -XX:-UseSplitVerifier webserver.aplication.IntFactorization 5
```

When executing this last instruction, it returns an exception:

```
Factoring 5...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: webserver.aplication.insProj
at webserver.aplication.IntFactorization.calcPrimeFactors(IntFactorization.java:22)
at webserver.aplication.IntFactorization.main(IntFactorization.java:59)
```

The instrumentations i'm making is incrementing a counter when a given method is executed and creating a file when the class ends execution. I know this works because i've tested outside these packages and it works fine.

Comment: do you define `package`s in the classes?

Comment: yes, in both im doing package webserver.aplication;

Comment: What is in IntFactorization.java line 22?

Comment: I'm not sure because the code was instrumented so there is no connection between .java and the .class files. What I'm adding are various chuncks but the error is probably the same for all. The first chunck is this routine.addBefore("webserver.aplication.insProj", "mcount", new Integer(1)); where before a routine (method) I add a counter. @Bajal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems BIT doesn't work well with packages. In the end, I removed insProj from any package and inserted its folder in the classpath. Then it began to work.